# Getting a Jetty exception when I reloading my GWT development web server

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

I'm getting this exception when restarting my GWT server.  I can't find any information on this exception that pertains to a server reload.  The exception doesn't seem to cause any problems but it's starting to annoy me.  The other developers in my office running the same GWT client and server code don't have this problem on their work stations.

Does anybody have any ideas about what could be causing this?

Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] Problem restoring session bxqd4t7l1o18
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager.restoreSession(HashSessionManager.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager.restoreSessions(HashSessionManager.java:360)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager.doStart(HashSessionManager.java:77)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:532)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:468)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:672)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the lone file that was in war/.sessions/

This gave me an "Unable to read from byte cache" exception, which I fixed by clearing my gwt-unitCache directory.  Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Jetty has serialized a previous session and is trying to restore it.  Here's a link to a howto on Jetty persistent sessions, maybe it can be of some help in turning this feature off [Jetty/Howto/Persisting Sessions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Persisting_Sessions)

Comment: I don't want to disable persistent sessions because I'd have to re-login every time I restart my web server.  But this pointed me in the right direction.  I ended up just clearing the war/.sessions folder.  Thanks!